# Multiple vector writers without locking

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-safety

I have a few threads writing in a vector. It's possible that different threads try to write the same byte. There is no reads. Can I use only an `atomic_fecth_or()`, like in the example, so the vector will become thread safe? It compiled with GCC without errors or warnings.

```
    std::vector<std::atomic<uint8_t>> MapVis(1024*1024); 

    void threador()
    {
    ...
    std::atomic_fetch_or(&MapVis[i], testor1); 
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why such approach wouldn't work, but it may be worth to try to supply an instance of vector (containing regular `uint8_t`) for each thread and then merge the results.

Comment: The vector has a fixed size known only at run time.

Comment: I can not divide the vector between threads because it represents a geometrical bit mapping (rectangle). The threads work in different regions but at the boundary's they can share some bytes.

Comment: "It is totally okay, to access std::vector from multiple threads, if you read objects, or if you write to different objects". As @VTT suggests in the comment above.

Answer (score 3):

> It compiled with GCC without errors or warnings

That doesn't mean anything because compilers don't perform that sort of concurrency analysis. There are dedicated static analysis tools that may do this with varying levels of success.

> Can I use only an `atomic_fetch_or` ...

you certainly can, and it will be safe at the level of each individual `std::atomic<uint8_t>`.

> ... the vector will become thread safe?

it's not sufficient that each element is accessed safely. You specifically need to avoid any operation that invalidates iterators (swap, resize, insert, push_back etc.).

I'd hesitate to say vector is thread-safe in this context - but you're limiting yourself to a thread-safe subset of its interface, so it will work correctly.

---

Note that as VTT suggests, keeping a separate partial vector per thread is better if possible. Partly because it's easier to prove correct, and partly because it avoids false sharing between cores.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes this is guaranteed to be thread safe** due to [atomic opperations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) being guaranteed of:

> Isolation from interrupts, signals, concurrent processes and threads

Thus when you access an element of `MapVis` atomically you're guaranteed that any other process writing to it has already completed. And that your process will not be interrupted till it finishes writing.

The concern if you were using non-atomic variables would be that:

1. Thread A fetches the value of `MapVis[i]`
2. Thread B fetches the value of `MapVis[i]`
3. Thread A writes the ored value to `MapVis[i]`
4. Thread B writes the ored value to `MapVis[i]`

As you can see Thread B needed to wait until Thread A had finished writing otherwise it's just going to stomp Thread A's changes to `MapVis[i]`. With atomic variables the fetch and write cannot be interrupted by concurrent threads. Meaning that Thread B couldn't interrupt Thread A's read-write operations.